# How to enter redemption code for Snow Leopard?

Tags: snow-leopard, imac, mac-appstore

I have purchased the Snow Leopard from the UK store for my iMac (Version 10.5.8, 2.8 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo and 2GB 800 Mhz DDR2 SDRAM memory). I received the redemption code 6 months ago and was so confused as it where to put this code. I wasn't around for the last 6 months and now want to try again. It says I need to enter this code in the app store but can't download this app store until I update my software! When I click the apple icon and go on software update, it says my software is up to date! This is such a catch 22, I really don't know what to do!

Comment: You don't need a redemtion code. There isn't an app store for Leopard. Also, 2 GB (if I remember correctly) isn't sufficient enough. Could you try telling all you tried?

Comment: Snow Leopard only requires 1 GB RAM. (More is always better though.)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to buy the [Snow Leopard installation DVD from the UK Apple Store](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard)

I'm not sure why you just got a redemption code. If you look at [this information page about older versions of OSX](http://store.apple.com/uk/help/downloads#olderversions) it says when you buy Snow Leopard you get a DVD, but if you buy Lion or Mountain Lion you get a redemption code. Are you sure you got Snow Leopard?